# Technical name for the removal of an image background

Tags: background, terminology, background-removal

Can someone remind me what the technical name is for the removal of a background from a still image?

Our photographer told me years ago, but I've since forgotten and it gets embarrassing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase I was looking for is 'deep-etching'.

Thanks for all the answers, guys.

Comment: Deep etching is how to achieve the effect after the plate is burned. The correct answer is given by Alan Gilbertson, below.

Answer (score 12):

Depending on the context and who you're talking to, this is referred to as "[keying](http://www.steves-digicams.com/knowledge-center/how-tos/photo-software/chroma-keying-in-photoshop.html#b)" (also referred to as Chroma Key), "[matting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matte_%28filmmaking%29)" (mostly video), "[masking](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/the-russell-brown-show/masking-basics-in-photoshop-cs5/)" (you'll come across "clipping mask" as a term which is interchangeable with "mask" in most cases) or extraction. These are all names for the same general technique, which is the basis of [Compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing).

Answer (score 3):

You might mean "background extraction".

Answer (score 3):

While I think Alan probably has it, `silhouetting` is an old school printer's term, `opaquing` (using a red clay-like paint to mask off portions of B&W film negatives), and `vignetting` all might fit the bill.

Answer (score 2):

You could say "Cut out" or "Image cut out"

Answer (score 1):

Another term could be "Isolated Image"